# hello.js 'Could not decode state parameter' in Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, firefox, oauth, hello.js

When using the oAuth Facebook API with hello.js in Firefox (40.0.2), once you authenticate, the redirect happens within the popup and it doesn't close. The console logs 'Could not decode state parameter'.

It's working fine in other browsers and in Firefox locally.

The only difference being that the live version of the site has a tracking query string that gets added to the URL during the auth request. And I think what is happening is that Firefox is having trouble extracting the location.hash.state.

Any ideas?

Here's the URL that is returned after authenticating:

```
http://example.com/?**QUERY_STRING**#state={**STATE_HASH**}&access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**&expires_in=1234
```